# Rabbitmq HTTP API with vhost

Tags: api, rest, rabbitmq

I don't understand how to resolve the HTTP API request I make. 
First of all I want to get the single queue statistics.  So I have made first the

```
curl..../api/queues/
```

worked fine and I received all queues. Then I tried to make a single one only. Since my vhost is equal "/"  I have no idea how to make the request I tried multiple things

```
curl..../api/queues///myqueuename
curl..../api/queues//myqueuename
```

and so on. I am getting frustrated becuase of it. How to resolve this without changing the actual vhost name "/" .

Answer (score 14):

I found solution myself. In this case instead of `/` it needs to use html url encoding for special characters in this case it was `%2F`.

Comment: one could also always UriEncode the vhost and queue names you pass on the url